# Installing perlapi-5.8.8

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu, perl-module

My problem is that I want to install the package libgtk-perl on ubuntu but it fails due to its unmet dependencies i.e perlapi-5.8.8, I have also tried doing auto dependency installation but that also fails. The problem is that it is a virtual package and even though perl-base is installed (As shown in the instructions) perlapi can't be installed. Please can anyone help me installing perlapu-5.8.8

```
adminuser@adminuser-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install libgtk-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.8.8
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
adminuser@adminuser-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install perlapi-5.8.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package perlapi-5.8.8 is a virtual package provided by:
  perl-base 5.8.8-7 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'perlapi-5.8.8' has no installation candidate
adminuser@adminuser-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install perl-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
perl-base is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: You might have more success if you would a use version of ubuntu which is still supported. 5.8.8 must have been Ubuntu 8.04/8.10 which is about 7 years old and long out of support. As far as I know that files are already removed from the official ubuntu servers so you will not be able to download the packages from there anymore.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich And `libgtk-perl` is almost certainly for GTK 1.x, which is even older. GTK 2.0 came out in 2002.

Comment: Well basically i need perlapi-5.8.8 and I am using ubuntu 14.04. I need if to run virtuoso

Comment: Don't virtuoso supply a version that uses libgtk2-perl? That's what recent versions of Ubuntu use.

Comment: Related?: http://serverfault.com/questions/631673/virtuoso-opensource-7-1-how-do-i-build-an-ubuntu-deb-package-from-github-sourc

Comment: [Perl 5.8.8 is nine years old](http://dev.perl.org/perl5/news/2006/perl-5.8.8.html). You really want to avoid software that old.

Comment: @DaveCross I am taking about this virtuoso (related to Virtual Machine Introspection) http://amnesia.gtisc.gatech.edu/~moyix/virtuoso/virtuoso_install.html

Comment: @AnasSaeed: Then they are the people you should contact to ask why they are using such old software :-)

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use Perl package Gtk. In order to do that, you're trying to install a binary that was built using Perl 5.8.8, which would require you switching to Perl 5.8.8 (or 5.8.9). Aside from being a major step backwards, you can't do what you want without breaking your system. Switching your Perl for Perl 5.8.8 would cause problems.

If your system doesn't provide a package for the Perl module Gtk for your version of Perl, install it yourself as follows (after installing the necessary C libraries):

```
cpan Gtk
```

Comment: This is the error I am getting                                                                                     make[1]: *** [xs/Gtk-1.2.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/adminuser/.cpan/build/Gtk-Perl-0.7010-2YVCBV/Gtk'
make: *** [subdirs] Error 2
  MLEHMANN/Gtk-Perl-0.7010.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK

Comment: Could you explain a little more cant find a way out

Comment: The message means `make` was unable to generate `xs/Gtk-1.2.o`. The way out is to look at the error you got during the attempt to generate `xs/Gtk-1.2.o`.